# After update to 6.2, FSE Editor is using only `contentSize`, ignoring `wideSide` setting

Tags: full-site-editing

Before 6.2 my editor (at least for this site and theme):

- offered the ability to set the width for each new block with a dropdown showing "narrow", "wide", "full" (I can't remember the exact options). Those options no longer
- honored the settings of `contentSize` and `wideSize` when opening a previously styled page with the "narrow", "wide" settings.

However, in 6.2 the client side looks fine, but the editor is jamming all previously set *wide* content into only the *narrow* width. (see attached image)

Note: when the page first loads in the editor, there is a flash where it is correct, then a moment later it reverts everything to the `contentSize`

If I load the twentytwentythree theme, it's fine: varying widths are honored.

The "Inner blocks use content width" toggle is on (green)

I've examined theme.json files of both themes and I'm not seeing anything that I feel would make the difference. I turned off my styles.css and no difference in the errant behavior. Here is the operable theme.json code:

```
        {
            "$schema": "http://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json",
            "version": 2,
            "settings": {
                "appearanceTools": true,
                "useRootPaddingAwareAlignments": false,
                "layout": {
                    "contentSize": "680px",
                    "wideSize": "1100px"
                },
                "color": {
                    "palette": [
```

The Inspector shows for the wrapper group and the column block:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="block-editor-block-list__block wp-block wp-block-group block-editor-block-list__layout is-layout-constrained" aria-label="Block: Group" data-type="core/group" data-title="Group">
    <div tabindex="0" class="block-editor-block-list__block wp-block alignwide wp-block-columns block-editor-block-list__layout wp-container-21 is-layout-flex is-nowrap" aria-label="Block: Columns" data-type="core/columns" data-title="Columns">
```

And finally an mockup of what it looks like. The editor should display it as the `wideSize` but is instead confining it to the `contentSize`.

What am I missing?
[image: image showing correct and incorrect editor display]

Comment: If it's only happening in a particular theme, you'll need to contact that theme's support team about this. (If it's happening in *all* themes, you might need to [open a ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/newticket) with WordPress support.)

Comment: It is my theme ;-)